# How to validate a form using php that only allows characters in names

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am asking this question because I am working on a project which entails signup wherein it can also allow numbers as names. But I want to allow only strings in names.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Take a look at [PHP filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a preg_match like this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $name) !== false) {
  // If name only contains characters from a-z
}
```

This only allows characters from a-z case insensitive, be aware no whitespace are allowed either.

You could also follow the fail early principle like this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $name) === false) {
  throw new RuntimeException('Only letters are allowed');
}
```

What this regex is telling you, is that the name must start (^) and end ($) with one or multiple letters ([a-z]+), and the last modifier flag (i) indicates it should be case insensitive. The slashes (/) indicates the escape characters for this expression.